# Relative Paths in different IDEs

Tags: python, path

lets assume following workspace is opened in an IDE:

```
myWorkspace
|- folder1
    |- file1.py
|- folder2
    |- file2.csv
```

I edit and execute file1.py and I want to use file2.csv in it. When I use PyCharm as an Editor, the correct way to do so is to use the path "../folder2/file2.csv". But when I use VSCode I need to use the path "folder2/file2.csv". So VSCode assumes the start to be the workspace folder, and it seems that my PyCharm Editor just takes the path where the file is executed as starting point.

My question: Which of these two ways is more common? What property causes such a behavior?

Comment: IMO the best way would be to extract the directory from the value of the built-in `__file__` variable in the `file1.py` script and create a path relative to that to open the `file2.csv`. This should be IDE independent.

Comment: @martineau I am implementing a Language Server, so I only know about which file is opened. In this example the User has ```file1.py``` opened and I can see that. If this user wants to import ```file2.csv``` I need to provide the correct path and I dont know which of the ones above is the correct one. There is no running file in this case.

Comment: In your question you said "...execute file1.py and I want to use file2.csv in it", so what you just said in your comment doesn't match that.

Comment: @martineau you are right. But still, I just wanted to know which of these cases is more common and what it is that causes this behavior.

Comment: "more common" with respect to what? Whether PyCharm is more popular than VSCode right now? You should strive to write code that is completely IDE independent — which is what I suggested in my initial comment.

Comment: @martineau well, I know that I don't know that much about Python, so I just wanted to know which is more common with respect to the experience all of the users here have.

Comment: Questions with only opinion-based answers are off-topic here…

Comment: @martineau this is my last comment about that. As I already said, I don't know too much about python, so I had no idea if there is a common thing or not.  And also I asked about what is causing that behavior, and I doubt that this is opinion-based.

Comment: The whole question would be moot if you just wrote IDE-independent code (which is the right thing to be doing anyway).

Comment: @martineau I agree, that writing Code that is independent of such things is better, but it is not possible in this case and i have to implement such a functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the more common way is the way VS code works. At least when running your program outside your IDE. The `myWorkspace` folder is your root folder for the project if I'm correct here.
But I don't see why you don't have anything in your root folder. Maybe you should create the main file for the entry point in your root folder and import the file from `folder1`.

This behavior is determined by how you execute your program.
If you run the script like this:

```sh
$ pwd
.../myworkplace
$ python folder1/file1.py
```

then the CWD (current working directory) will be the `myworkplace` folder and the `folder2/file2.csv` approach will work.

If you run the script like this:

```sh
$ pwd
.../myworkplace/folder1
$ python file1.py
```

then the CWD will be the `folder1` folder and the `../folder2/file2.csv` route will be the correct one.